# How to compare image with robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I am new to robot framework and trying to compare two images. I did some R&D from my end and found that there is existing RobotAppEyes library which helps t compare images.

**Link1 :** http://navinet.github.io/Robot-AppEyes/RobotAppEyes-KeywordDocumentation.html#Compare%20Image

**Link2:** https://github.com/NaviNet/Robot-AppEyes

I am using same library to compare images but facing below issue while comparing two images.

```
** Settings ***
Library                 Selenium2Library
Library                 RobotAppEyes

*** Test Cases ***
RobotAppEyes 1.0 Test
    Open Browser    http://www.google.com.uk    gc      
    Maximize Browser Window     
    Open Eyes Session   http://www.google.com.uk    RobotAppEyes_Test   NaviNet_RobotAppEyes_Test1  JkaJK50dp1NTEhPufx08SaztsXmfBZas8z0MZVcaqcA110  
    # ${isOpen}=    Eyes Session Is Open                    
    # Log    ${isOpen}
    Compare Image        C:\\Users\\Downloads\\logo.png       C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\logo.png     ignore_mismatch=False    includeEyesLog=False     httpDebugLog=False
    Check Eyes Region   .//*[@id='splash']/div[1]       500     120     logo
    Run Keyword If  ${isOpen}==True Close Eyes Session
    Close Eyes Session
```

**Response after executing robot script:**

```
RobotAppEyes 1.0 Test                                                 | FAIL |
TypeError: _create_match_data_bytes() takes at least 6 arguments (5 given)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can anyone help me image comparison with the help of robot framework ?

Comment: _create_match_data_bytes looks like it might be a sub-function of Compare Image, possibly, but after reading the documentation, I can't find a reason why Compare Image wouldn't have enough arguments. Do you happen to know if it's a sub-function of a different part of your code?

Comment: Yes i think so, Please find below link for more details:                                                           https://github.com/NaviNet/Robot-AppEyes/blob/master/RobotAppEyes/RobotAppEyes.py                                       Also if anyone know any other method with working example please let me know for image comparison using robot framework.

Comment: Well... are you looking for something that compares two images exactly and returns a failure if they are not exactly the same down to the pixel?

Comment: Yes I am trying to compare two images. Please help me with working example.

Comment: Just to clear up one more thing so that I know my solution will work for you, are both pictures visible to your eye on the screen at the same time?

Comment: My intention is like passing path of one image which is stored at my local machine and try to pass another image at run time. But as i mentioned I need one working example so that I can at least check how its working

Comment: Ah, never mind, then. I know of a way to check a local image against an image on the screen, but that's it.

Comment: Can you please share code ?

Comment: I'll share it as an answer, then isolate the piece of code that does what I said. It's a custom, python-based keyword.

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer after discussion in the comments. It is not a perfect answer to Dipak's problem and I realize this, but he asked me to post it.

```
 from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
    import pyautogui as pag

class click_by_image(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.selenium_lib = None

    def click_by_image(self, image_name):
        """
        Click the center of a rectangle on the screen given the
        image_name of the image rectangle to search for
        :param image_name: Path to image
        """
        #   If ExtendedSelenium2Library instance is undefined
        if self.selenium_lib is None:
            # Instantiate ExtendedSelenium2Library
            self.selenium_lib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('ExtendedSelenium2Library')
        pag.click(pag.locateCenterOnScreen(str(image_name)))
```

That's the full keyword it comes from. It's slippery with small pictures (~20px by ~40px is where it has problems, though I haven't exactly measured it), but it works very well with large ones, assuming the exact set of pixels exists on the screen. That's *anywhere* on the screen, not just within the DOM, so this is what I use to click between tabs and interact with a normal desktop.

To use this keyword, feed your local copy of the picture to `click_by_image()` as either an absolute or relative path, either works, and it'll work as documented.

The specific code I mentioned is `pag.locateCenterOnScreen()`, which comes from pyautogui. It returns a set of coordinates, so if you don't get those coordinates, then your image does not appear on the screen. If you do, then you know that a) your image exists and b) where it is.

Answer (score 0):

**Able to resolve this issue with image Magic**

```
Compare Images
    [Arguments]      ${Reference_Image_Path}    ${Test_Image_Path}    ${Allowed_Threshold}
    ${TEMP}=         Replace String     ${IMAGE_COMPARATOR_COMMAND}    __REFERENCE__     ${Reference_Image_Path}
    ${COMMAND}=      Replace String     ${TEMP}    __TEST__     ${Test_Image_Path}
    Log              ${Allowed_Threshold}
    Log              Executing: ${COMMAND}
    ${RC}            ${OUTPUT}=     Run And Return Rc And Output    ${COMMAND}
    # ${RC}            ${OUTPUT}=     Run And Return Rc And Output    C:/"Program Files"/ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16/convert.exe    C:/Users/user/imagecompare/Test/src/reference-screenshots/reference-1.png    C:/Users/user/imagecompare/Test/src/reference-screenshots/reference-11.png -metric RMSE -compare -format "%[distortion]" info:
    Log              Return Code: ${RC}
    Log              Return Output: ${OUTPUT}
    ${RESULT}        Evaluate    ${OUTPUT} < ${Allowed_Threshold}
    Should be True   ${RESULT}
```

https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2017/09/robot-framework-compare-images-screenshots/